# Need help, Cannot convert value of type '(NSURLRequest!, NSHTTPURLResponse!, UIImage!)

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

Im getting a error which says

> Cannot convert value of type (NSURLRequest!, NSHTTPURLResponse!, UIImage!) -> Void' to expected argument type '((NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, UIImage) -> Void)?

Here is the code

```
import UIKit

class RoutineCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var bannerImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var routineTitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var shortDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

var routine: Routine! {
    didSet {
        routineTitleLabel.text = routine.title
        shortDescriptionLabel.text = routine.shortDescription
        bannerImageView.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: routine.bannerImageUrl)!)
        bannerImageView.setImageWithURLRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: routine.bannerImageUrl)!), placeholderImage: nil, success: { (request: NSURLRequest!, response: NSHTTPURLResponse!, image: UIImage!) -> Void in
            self.bannerImageView.alpha = 0.0
            self.bannerImageView.image = image
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.bannerImageView.alpha = 1.0
            })
        }, failure: nil)
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    bannerImageView.image = nil
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration for the `bannerImageView.setImageWithURLRequest` callback is wrong

```
(request: NSURLRequest!, response: NSHTTPURLResponse!, image: UIImage!)
```

you need to use the following

```
(request: NSURLRequest, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, image: UIImage)
```

Comment: This works. You should try this

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much